# spring cloud config server - No such label: master

Tags: spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry, spring-cloud-config

My cloud config server was returning the property files but now I am seeing the below error. Please can you let me know how this can be fixed?

This is deployed in pivotal cloud foundry environment.

```
{
"timestamp": 1464375520539
"status": 404
"error": "Not Found"
"exception": "org.springframework.cloud.config.server.environment.NoSuchLabelException"
"message": "No such label: master"
"path": "/couchbase-data/dev"
}
```

**application.yml**

```
---
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.company.com/username/ordering-properties
          username: username
          password: "{cipher}03f0ac5cc43d913bbd45155f852d1e5c88542878491a1fc89185feea93a40084"
          search-paths: couchbase-data

security:
  basic:
    enabled: true
  user:
    name: ordering_config
    password: "{cipher}dc56acf65f93b5485c87de1a9965e76a2d0b642a0839027deffdbc35f922746f"
```

**manifest.yml**

```
 ---
    name: orderingconfigserver
    memory: 2048M
    instances: 1
    timeout: 180
    env:
      ENCRYPT_KEY: ORDERING
```

After I deploy the app , the first hit to the endpoint returns the below error :

```
{
"timestamp": 1464377154415
"status": 500
"error": "Internal Server Error"
"exception": "java.lang.IllegalStateException"
"message": "Cannot clone or checkout repository"
"path": "/couchbase-data/dev"
}
```

Comment: Post more details about your config server (`bootstrap.yml` and etc)

Comment: Hi  Ali , updated the details.

Comment: Do you have a sub-directory in your git repo called `couchbase-data`?

Comment: Yes , I do and it was working until few minutes ago. The only change that I did since then is unbound the app from rabbitmq as I thought it wasn't required.

Comment: The first hit that make to the endpoint after deployment of this artifact return status 500. I have pasted details related to same as well in the post now.

Comment: When I removed the password cipher and gave the actual password , it again works.

Comment: just a hint: if you are using spring-cloud-config server to encrypt your password, you need patch your jvm to do that..

Comment: I deployed this into pivotal cloud foundry env and I guess the build pack already has jvm patched to do that. When I hit the url , I'm being asked for the credentials for the service. I provided the one in security section. Do you think it is because of jvm build pack not having appropriate security patch ?

Comment: Additionally, whichever 'key' you used to create the password cipher needs to be known about by the config server.  They way the config server works is that it decrpyts the ciphers on clone, and it has to have the same key that the ciphers were encrypted with.  The key can be specified with the property:  encrypt.key=MyKey to your config server.

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_creating_a_key_store_for_testing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your git repo has the main branch name as "main" instead of "master", I would recommend you to add a new property to change default-label as below:

```
spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=main
```

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64991698/3809696) for additional info.